# Debugging android widgets

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, widget

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.2 (latest) while attempting to make a widget and I've noticed debugger is close to impossible to attach.

**Problem 1:** When using "Debug app" option (with both physical devices and virtual), it will just go through series of:

> Waiting for application to come online: com.example.[application]|
>   com.example.[application].test

and finally say

> Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.

**Problem 2:** I found out I can attach debugger manually, with some patience, but widget process seems to stop on it's own and disconnect the debugger when it happens.

**Question:**
Is there any method that would allow uninterrupted widget debugging? Automatic debugger attachment would be a bonus.

EDIT:

**Solution to problem 2:** Automatic process closures seemed to have been crashes caused by thrown exceptions (without any notification by OS). Activating logcat and following error messages helped me track down and fix the likely cause. After this I've been able to keep the debugger attached, even if I attached it manually.

Comment: "Solution to problem 2: Automatic process closures seemed to have been crashes caused by thrown exceptions (without any notification by OS). Activating logcat and following error messages helped me track down and fix the likely cause. After this I've been able to keep the debugger attached, even if I attached it manually." So you cannot just start and debug at the same time? you are obligated to attach manually?

Answer (score 2):

as far as I remember Android Widgets do not run in your process they run in the Android launcher process of the device.

So you will want to attached the debugger to the launcher process (not `com.example.[application]`).

---

Failing that you can add lots of logs :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing me to the logs. I'm not 100% certain yet, but I think process termination may have been happening due to a thrown exception, that I didn't even know about until I activated logcat. I can confirm that debugger attaches to widget's own process (not launcher's).

Comment: how to attach the debugger to that process?

Comment: @alexpfx in android studio when you select "attach debugger" (not "run in debug mode") then you should get a dialog with a list of processess you can choose to attach to

Comment: @Blundell after attaching the debugger, it just terminates debugging after couple of seconds, any ideas? Thank you

Comment: @Sam this usually happens when a separate process has crashed, i.e. it crashes thats why it stopped, and your debug breakpoint was in the wrong place

Comment: @Blundell not sure, i just placed the break point on the calling of a function something like `Boolean isConnected = isDeviceConnected()` it didn't go inside the method to crash *I have another break point inside the method* I also noticed If I placed the break point inside `onUpdate` it won't stop, but it will inside `onReceive` for button click but it just stops right after reaching the break point.

Comment: check your logcat there should be a crash in there someone (turn off the filter for your own process)